# Classification: Dealing with Abstain/Rejected Class

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, libsvm, knn

I am asking for your input and/help on a classification problem. If anyone have any references that I can read to help me solve my problem even better.

I have a classification problem of four discrete and very well separated classes. However my input is continuous and has a high frequency (50Hz), since its a real-time problem.

[image: Equal Weight Decision Boundary]

The circles represent the clusters of the classes, the blue line the decision boundary and Class 5 equals the (neutral/resting  do nothing class). This class is the rejected class. However the problem is that when I move from one class to the other I activate a lot of false positives in the transition movements, since the movement is clearly non-linear.
For example, every time I move from class 5 (neutral class) to 1 I first see a lot of 3's before getting to the 1 class.

Ideally, I will want my decision boundary to look like the one in the picture below where the rejected class is Class =5. Has a higher decision boundary than the others classes to avoid misclassification during transition. I am currently implementing my algorithm in Matlab using naive bayes, kNN, and SVMs optimized algorithms using Matlab.

Question: What is the best/common way to handle abstain/rejected classes classes? Should I use (fuzzy logic, loss function, should I include resting cluster in the training)?

[image: Ideal Decision Boundary]

Comment: What you mean by movement is unclear and ambiguous. For example, how can you get a false "3" when moving from class 5 to class 1 in the diagram listed above? At no point does 3 get in the way. That you input has a high frequency is a confusing statement as well. Pleasure further define what it is you actually mean and want to accomplish

Comment: You are correct that they don't get in the way. However, the example show above is hypothetical, and the data is non-linear so even if I physically do not pass through 3 to get to 1, I can still see it sometimes due to non-linearity.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with Boosting, you can try **AdaBoost.MH** with **abstain**. In the regular version of AdaBoost (for a binary classification task), each weak classifier outputs a label which is either +1 or -1. In the version with abstain, each weak classifier is allowed to "abstain" by predicting 0, which allows the weak classifier to say "I don't know". The same idea can be extended to multi-class problems by decomposing every instance into multiple binary classification problems.

In your case, you can map class 5 to an "abstain" prediction.

Before decomposing, suppose your training instances look like:

```
x1 -> 1
x2 -> 5
```

So after decomposing, your training instances look like:

```
x1 -> 1          (predicting +1)
x1 -> not 2      (predicting -1) 
x1 -> not 3      (predicting -1)
x1 -> not 4      (predicting -1)
x2 -> abstain    (predicting 0)
x2 -> not 1      (predicting +1)
x2 -> not 2      (predicting +1)
x2 -> not 3      (predicting +1)
x2 -> not 4      (predicting +1)
```

In each boosting iteration, you will choose a feature from the training instances and construct a weak learner (decision stump) that minimizes the prediction loss and updates the weight associated with each training instance. "x2 -> abstain" does not affect the prediction loss by predicting 0, however all the other decomposed training instances like "x2-> not 1", "x2-> not 2", etc, still helps the system to recognize the negative effect of x2 when classifying the instance as 1 through 4.

[Here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.4002) is the classic paper that includes the idea of AdaBoost with abstain:

Robert E. Schapire, Yoram Singer Improved Boosting Algorithms Using Confidence-rated Predictions.

[This](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr08/cos424/readings/SchapireSinger2000.pdf) is another paper that has more details for AdaBoost.MH with abstain and an application in text categorization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for pointing out to the papers, I'll take a look at it and see if it can help. Do you know any libraries (like Weka) that implement this in Matlab, C or Java, so that I can play with it before actually having to implement it.